# symfony - admin list drag and dtop items

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm looking at creating a drag and drop interface for an admin module list, but I'm unsure how to go about this

I've seen a couple of tutorials, using Propel and SF1.2, but I'm using doctrine and 1.4.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read this: http://www.symfony-project.org/more-with-symfony/1_4/en/09-Doctrine-Form-Inheritance

It seems it's already there.

Comment: I haven't read that. But there is no real example code for the AJAX drag and drop. Just the schema relations and some methods to move code. Would I need to implement these methods and implement my own drag and drop using jquery?

Comment: @terrid25 I think it is already implemented. Did you try to generate admin using Doctrine?

Comment: I didn't see the stuff towards the middle with the drag and drop stuff. Got it all working now though! thank you!